# How to create and use two Python iterables of shared memory items, and maintain the shared memory during usage?

Tags: python, memory, reference, iterable

How can I create a pair of iterables containing the same items (not just copies, but shared memory of items) **but in different order**, and such that a change to an item in one of the iterables will be reflected in the other iterable?

For example:

```
>>> x = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [x[1], x[2], x[3], x[0]]
>>> x[2] is y[1]
True
```

Great so far, but if I make a change to one of the items in an iterable, it ends up creating a new item (new memory) space, not changing the item in that same memory space.

```
>>> x[2] *= 5
>>> x[2] is y[1]
False
>>> x[2]
10
>>> y[1]
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each item in a box:

```
>>> x = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
>>> y = [x[1], x[2], x[3], x[0]]
>>> x[2] is y[1]
True
>>> x[2][0] *= 5
>>> x[2] is y[1]
True
>>> x[2]
[10]
>>> y[1]
[10]
```

Here I'm using a list, but any mutable container will do.

Comment: Thanks, @Samwise! I had tried something like that before, but with this line instead: x[2] = [x[2][0]*5]. Now I see why that failed. I was creating a new list (what I'll think of unofficially from now on as a "container") rather than replacing the 0th item in the existing list. Great!